# Process all checkboxes of all pages on archieve function in javascript Datatables

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jsp

I have this code that check all the checkboxes of every page of my dataTable

ListDocs.jsp

```
     <th  class="th2"> <input type="checkbox" id="select-all"  name="checkDocs"   title="Archivamiento" /></th>
    <td align="center"><input class="ck" title='Archivar' type="checkbox" id="dArc<%=cb.getIdDocumento()%>" value="<%=cb.getIdDocumento()%>"/> </td>
    <td align="center"><input class="inv" title='Invalidar' type="checkbox" id="dInv<%=cb.getIdDocumento()%>" value="<%=cb.getNodo()%>" <%=invalid%> <%=disabled%> onclick="invalida(this)"/> </td>


 $("#select-all").click(function(event) {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $("#tablaResultados tbody input[type='checkbox']:not(.inv):not(:checked)").prop("checked", true);
            // loop through all pages and select all checkboxes
            var table = $('#tablaResultados').DataTable();
            for (var i = 1; i <= table.page.info().pages; i++) {
                table.page(i).draw(false);
                $("#tablaResultados tbody input[type='checkbox']:not(.inv):not(:checked)").prop("checked", true);
            }
        } else {
            $("#tablaResultados tbody input[type='checkbox']:not(.inv):checked").prop("checked", false);
            // loop through all pages and unselect all checkboxes
            var table = $('#tablaResultados').DataTable();
            for (var i = 1; i <= table.page.info().pages; i++) {
                table.page(i).draw(false);
                $("#tablaResultados tbody input[type='checkbox']:not(.inv):checked").prop("checked", false);
            }
        }
    });
```

index.jsp

```
    function archivarTodo(){
    var trans =  document.getElementById('transf').value;
        if(trans == '1'){
        if(nodoCarp===""){
            alert("Debe seleccionar una Carpeta");
        }else{
            var checkboxValues = "";

            $("#listado").contents().find(".ck:input:checked").each(function() {
                checkboxValues += $(this).val() + ",";
            });
            
            checkboxValues = checkboxValues.substring(0, checkboxValues.length-1);
            
            if (checkboxValues===""||checkboxValues==="on"){
                alert("No se han seleccionado Documentos para Archivar");
                return;
            }

           if(confirm("Sure?'")){
                esperarCarp2("../imagenes/loadingAnimation.gif","500","1000","../archivar/ArchivarDoctosFiduciario.jsp?nodo="+nodoCarp+"&idDocs="+checkboxValues); 
                }//Cambio estirar pantalla "esperarCarp2"
            }
        }else{alert("No tiene permisos para Archivar");}    
    }
```

The method archivarTodo on index.jsp works like a charm but only archives all the checkboxes checked on the current page that you are visualizing, it's possible to manage this method to  archive all the checkbox checked on the entire datatable not only the current one that you are visualizing.

To get more context $("#listado") is an iframe that shows ListDocs.jsp content.

It's possible to accomplish that?

yeah it was possible HERE IS THE SOLUTION:

```js
function archivarTodo() {
  var trans = document.getElementById('transf').value;
  console.log("Trans value:", trans);
  if (trans == '1') {
    if (nodoCarp === "") {
      alert("Debe seleccionar una Carpeta");
    } else {
      var iframe = document.getElementById('listado');
      var iframeWindow = iframe.contentWindow;
      var dataTable = iframeWindow.$('#tablaResultados').DataTable();
      var checkboxValues = "";

      dataTable.$('.ck:input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
        console.log("Checkbox value:", $(this).val());
        checkboxValues += $(this).val() + ",";
      });

      checkboxValues = checkboxValues.substring(0, checkboxValues.length - 1);
      console.log("Selected checkboxes:", checkboxValues);

      if (checkboxValues === "") {
        alert("No se han seleccionado Documentos para Archivar");
        return;
      }
```

Comment: A simple approach will be to call a different endpoint that accepts the filter params you used to fetch the data and archives all related records

Comment: can you be more specific?

Comment: create a function like `archiveAllTodos(){...` at the backend, and call it with the `archivarTodo()` function at the frontend if the `select-all` checkbox is checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have a jsp route with a java method called `archiveAllTodos(){`.

```js
function archivarTodo() {
  var selectedAll = document.getElementById("select-all").checked;

  if (selectedAll) {
    if (confirm("Sure?'")) {
        // call the route that has the archiveAllTodos() method
        esperarCarp2(
            "../imagenes/loadingAnimation.gif", "500", "1000", "../archivar/ArchivarAllTodos.jsp"
            //OR
            // "../imagenes/loadingAnimation.gif", "500", "1000", "../archivar/ArchivarDoctosFiduciario.jsp?archiveAll=true"
        );
    }
  } else {
    var trans = document.getElementById("transf").value;
    if (trans == "1") {
      if (nodoCarp === "") {
        alert("Debe seleccionar una Carpeta");
      } else {
        var checkboxValues = "";

        $("#listado").contents().find(".ck:input:checked").each(function () {
            checkboxValues += $(this).val() + ",";
          });

        checkboxValues = checkboxValues.substring(0, checkboxValues.length - 1);

        if (checkboxValues === "" || checkboxValues === "on") {
          alert("No se han seleccionado Documentos para Archivar");
          return;
        }

        if (confirm("Sure?'")) {
          esperarCarp2(
            "../imagenes/loadingAnimation.gif", "500", "1000",  "../archivar/ArchivarDoctosFiduciario.jsp?nodo=" + nodoCarp + "&idDocs=" +  checkboxValues
          );
        } //Cambio estirar pantalla "esperarCarp2"
      }
    } else {
      alert("No tiene permisos para Archivar");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: actually your code help me to figure it out the solution